# спарсить вложенный json

Tags: json, golang

У меня есть структура

```
type notifiStruct struct {
 r_id      string        `json:"r_id"`
 pm        int           `json:"pm"`

}
```

Есть json строка

```
jsons := `{"r_id":"861bb2bd-c9e4-4121-a572-8eff2a89775d", "pm":25, "dt":[{"r_id":"861bb2bd-c9e4-4121-a572-8eff2a89775d","ni":73407},{"r_id":"861bb2bd-c9e4-4121-a572-8eff2a89775d","ni":73291}, }`
```

Я хочу пройтись по массиву dt циклом.
У меня получилось спарсить json таким образом.

```
var m notifiStruct
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsons), &m)
   
fmt.Println(jsons)
```

Но я не понимаю как мне спарсить dt.

Answer (score -1):

```go
type notifiStruct struct {
    r_id string `json:"r_id"`
    pm int `json:"pm"`
    dt []struct {
        r_id string `json:"r_id"`
        ni int `json:"ni"`
    } `json:"dt"`
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: попробуйте поработать с рекомендованной вами структурой, например получить из нее json https://go.dev/play/p/aMyy0_xzG53